# check statement and replace values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table that shows how many days a store opened in a week, and how many items were sold in that week, like that

```
ID days items
1   4   10  
2   5   50  
3   4   100 
4   3   80  
5   1   30  
6   2   50  
7   5   80
```

I want to add a column that is TRUE if that store opened for more than 4 days and sold more than 50 items.

```
ID days items check
1   4   10    FALSE
2   5   50    TRUE  
3   4   100   TRUE  
4   3   80    FALSE 
5   1   30    FALSE 
6   2   50    FALSE 
7   5   80    TRUE
```

How can i do it with the `:=` function from `data.table`?
It can be done with a FOR loop and an IF statement, but it is costly, since this table is huge.

Comment: This is extremely basic. Have you studied the data.table vignettes? They show how to do this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)  
df[, check := days > 4 & items > 50]
```

This gives us:

```
   ID days items check
1:  1    4    10 FALSE
2:  2    5    50 FALSE
3:  3    4   100 FALSE
4:  4    3    80 FALSE
5:  5    1    30 FALSE
6:  6    2    50 FALSE
7:  7    5    80  TRUE
```

To get your desired result, you would add `=` (though this does not match the description in your text):

```
df[, check := days >= 4 & items >= 50]

   ID days items check
1:  1    4    10 FALSE
2:  2    5    50  TRUE
3:  3    4   100  TRUE
4:  4    3    80 FALSE
5:  5    1    30 FALSE
6:  6    2    50 FALSE
7:  7    5    80  TRUE
```